# Why I am only seeing the first character

Tags: c

**Question :**

I know I should be using a character array but character data are stored in as their corresponding numerical value; So we can say both **int array** and **character array** are same the only difference is; generally character uses **1 byte** and int uses **4 bytes**.

**My Problem :**

I have an int array; I am storing data into that array but when I tried to print that array using **printf and %s** its only printing first character from that array

When **%s** is used with **printf** it searches for **null character** i.e. **\0**, to know where to stop. In my code I am putting **/0** explicitly to the end of string.

**Code(Edited)** :

```
/* Write a program to print all input lines that are longer than 80
characters. */

    #include <stdio.h>
    #define MAXCHAR 80
    #define LINES   1000

    int main() {
        int i, c = 0;
        int data[LINES]; 

        while(c != EOF) {
            for(i = 0; i < LINES - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
                data[i] = c;
            printf("Value of i after for = %d\n",i );

            if(c == '\n') {
                data[i] = c;
                ++i;
            }
            data[i] = '\0';
            if(i >= MAXCHAR + 2)
                printf("%s\n",data);                        
            printf("Value of i = %d\n",i );
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I apologies for that, I edited the question

Comment: Code is using wrong format specifier and hence UB. Zzzzz. Next. Anyway, think about it: an `int` might contain a zero byte as part of its object representation.

Comment: Where I am using wrong format specifier @underscore_d

Comment: `printf("%s\n",data)` where `%s` means '_here is a string, honest_' and `data` is not a string. Anyway, the question lacks context. What are you **actually** trying to do? What output do you actually want, for what input?

Comment: @underscore_d with due respect, I think format specifier are used to print data with desired format.... Here  I only want to print my int data into a string

Comment: @Bhaskar then you use the format specifier for `int`.  he's right, you are using the wrong specifier.

Comment: or format specifier is correct and the array is the wrong type.

Comment: That UB could be done away with a simple cast to `char*`. I think OP's question is why he sees only the first character.

Comment: @Bhaskar & with respect, it's not about what you think; it's about how the language works, whether or not it matches your intuition - & in this case it does not, because a basic facet of `printf()` _et al._, which I'd hope is emphasised in whatever reading you have, is they trust you're really passing the types your format specifiers claim - & if you don't, your program has undefined behaviour & its results are therefore meaningless. Your question mixes up types, without any apparent reason, i.e. it's totally opaque why you felt a need to involve `int` at all.

Comment: @underscore_d I apologizes for my mistake, thanks a lot for that info

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a `char` array containing the string "Hello\0" it will look like this:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| H | e | l | l | o |\0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Or if we show the integer value of those characters it looks like this:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  72 | 101 | 108 | 108 | 111 |   0 |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

So if we have an array of `int` containing the same values it looks like this:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|        72 |       101 |       108 |       108 |       111 |         0 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Or in hexadecimal, and assuming 16-bit ints, it looks like this:

```
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| 0048 | 0065 | 006C | 006C | 006F | 0000 |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

Or looking at the individual bytes, and assuming little-endian byte order, it looks like this:

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 48 | 00 | 65 | 00 | 6C | 00 | 6C | 00 | 6F | 00 | 00 | 00 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

So if we have an `int` array containing the integers corresponding to the characters in a string, and if (despite the gross type incompatibility) we try to print them using `printf` and `%s`, it will look at the first byte which is `48` which is an `H`, and print it, but then right after that it will see a 0 byte, which it will interpret as the end of the string, and stop.

Comment: So both should print same thing

Comment: @Bhaskar Reread the whole answer.  You may only have seen the first part, as I was editing.

Comment: _"So if we have an `int` array containing the integers corresponding to the characters in a string, and we try to print that string using `printf` and `%s`"_ It's not a string, and the `printf` invokes undefined behaviour. The real answer is probably another question, i.e. asking what the OP is trying to do, and how this probably isn't the way to do it.

Comment: @underscore_d You're right, I should not have referred to an `int *` as "the string".  Fixed.